# Navbar disappears after scrollIntoView() use on mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Problem:** NavBar disappears after `scrollIntoView()` used on mobile view.

**Related JS**

```
function disableScroll() {
  window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false); // older FF
  window.addEventListener(wheelEvent, preventDefault, wheelOpt); // modern desktop
  window.addEventListener('touchmove', preventDefault, wheelOpt); // mobile
  window.addEventListener('keydown', preventDefaultForScrollKeys, false);
}

function enableScroll() {
  window.removeEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false);
  window.removeEventListener(wheelEvent, preventDefault, wheelOpt);
  window.removeEventListener('touchmove', preventDefault, wheelOpt);
  window.removeEventListener('keydown', preventDefaultForScrollKeys, false);
}

function scroll_to_chapters() {
    const chapters = document.getElementsByClassName("chapter_list")[0];
    if (nav.classList.contains("nav-active")) {
        navLinks.forEach((link) => {
            if (link.style.animation) {
                link.style.animation = '';
            }
        });
        enableScroll();
        burger.classList.toggle('toggle');
        nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
    }
    chapters.scrollIntoView({ block: 'start',  behavior: 'smooth' })
}

const navSlide = ()=> {
    burger.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
        //Toggle NavBar
        nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
        //Animate Links
        navLinks.forEach((link, index)=> {
            if (link.style.animation) {
                enableScroll();
                link.style.animation = '';
            }
            else {
                disableScroll();
                link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 0.5}s`;
            }
        });
        burger.classList.toggle('toggle');
    });
}
```

I'm not quite sure but there might be a problem with the disabling and enabling scrolling. I didn't want mobile users to be able to scroll while the navbar menus are opened.

**Navbar HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="fix">
        <header>
            <div class="container">
                <nav>
                <a href="/" data-attr="img"><img src="{% static 'img/northernlogo.png' %}" class="logo" alt="logo"></a>
                <ul class="nav-links">
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/" onclick="scroll_to_chapters();return false;">Chapters</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/links">Links</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="burger">
                    <div class="line1"></div>
                    <div class="line2"></div>
                    <div class="line3"></div>
                </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Related CSS**

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0;
}

.container::after {
    content: '';
    display: grid;
    clear: both;
}

.burger {
    display: none;
    margin-top: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.burger div {
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    background: #EEEEEE;
    margin: 5px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .wrapper {
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
    }
    .nav-links {
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0.5em 1.5em -0.5em black;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        height: 100%;
        top: 70px;
        background-color: #3a345c;
        z-index: 99;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
    }
    .nav-links li {
        opacity: 0;
        padding-bottom: 50px;
        padding-top: 50px;
    }

    .nav-links li a {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .burger {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

**Picture of the Error**

| Before | After |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Before] | [image: After] |

**How to Reproduce**

Open [the website](https://www.northernbladetl.com/) on mobile view. Open the navbar from the home menu and click chapters. It'll take you to the chapters but now the navbar is gone.

Editor's note:

> The accepted answer features a self-contained reproducible example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because `.nav-links` are `position: absolute` with:

- a `position: static` (by default) parent `.fix`, and
- a `position: relative` grandparent `.wrapper`.

In this case, `scrollIntoView({block: 'start', ...})` scrolls `.fix` out of view of `.wrapper` before scrolling `.wrapper` itself.

- `{block: 'center', ...}` does the same.
- `{block: 'end', ...}` and `{block: 'nearest', ...}` don't.

You can't scroll `.fix` back into view because `.wrapper` has `overflow: hidden`.

## Solution

Make `.fix` have `position: relative` and make `.nav-links` have `height: 100vh`.

```css
.fix {
  position: relative;
}
.nav-links {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Run this code snippet to reproduce the problem, and click on the toggle to try with answer:

```js
const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');

// left: 37, up: 38, right: 39, down: 40,
// spacebar: 32, pageup: 33, pagedown: 34, end: 35, home: 36
var keys = {
  37: 1,
  38: 1,
  39: 1,
  40: 1
};

function preventDefault(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}

function preventDefaultForScrollKeys(e) {
  if (keys[e.keyCode]) {
    preventDefault(e);
    return false;
  }
}

// modern Chrome requires { passive: false } when adding event
var supportsPassive = false;
try {
  window.addEventListener("test", null, Object.defineProperty({}, 'passive', {
    get: function() {
      supportsPassive = true;
    }
  }));
} catch (e) {}

var wheelOpt = supportsPassive ? {
  passive: false
} : false;
var wheelEvent = 'onwheel' in document.createElement('div') ? 'wheel' : 'mousewheel';

// call this to Disable
function disableScroll() {
  window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false); // older FF
  window.addEventListener(wheelEvent, preventDefault, wheelOpt); // modern desktop
  window.addEventListener('touchmove', preventDefault, wheelOpt); // mobile
  window.addEventListener('keydown', preventDefaultForScrollKeys, false);
}

// call this to Enable
function enableScroll() {
  window.removeEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false);
  window.removeEventListener(wheelEvent, preventDefault, wheelOpt);
  window.removeEventListener('touchmove', preventDefault, wheelOpt);
  window.removeEventListener('keydown', preventDefaultForScrollKeys, false);
}

function read_more_less(button) {
  var x = $('#more');
  $(button).find('i').remove();
  if ($(button).text().trim() === 'Read more') {
    $(button).html($('<i/>', {
      class: 'fas fa-sort-down'
    })).append(' Read less');
    x.fadeIn();
  } else {
    $(button).html($('<i/>', {
      class: 'fas fa-sort-up'
    })).append(' Read more');
    x.fadeOut();
  }
}

function scroll_to_chapters() {
  const chapters = document.getElementsByClassName("chapter_list")[0];
  if (nav.classList.contains("nav-active")) {
    navLinks.forEach((link) => {
      if (link.style.animation) {
        link.style.animation = '';
      }
    });
    enableScroll();
    burger.classList.toggle('toggle');
    nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
  }
  chapters.scrollIntoView({
    block: 'start',
    behavior: 'smooth'
  })
}

const navSlide = () => {
  burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    //Toggle NavBar
    nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
    //Animate Links
    navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
      if (link.style.animation) {
        enableScroll();
        link.style.animation = '';
      } else {
        disableScroll();
        link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 0.5}s`;
      }
    });
    burger.classList.toggle('toggle');
  });
}
navSlide();

function toggleAnswer(button) {
  var wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
  wrapper.classList.toggle('answer');
  button.innerHTML = wrapper.classList.contains('answer') ? 'Click to try without answer' : 'Click to try with answer';
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #212121;
  font-family: 'Glory', serif !important;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0;
}

.container::after {
  content: '';
  display: grid;
  clear: both;
}

.burger {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.burger div {
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #EEEEEE;
  margin: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

header {
  background: #3a345c;
}

nav {
  justify-content: space-around;
  display: flex;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav a:not([data-attr="img"]) {
  color: #eeeeee;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 15px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
  }
  .nav-links {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0.5em 1.5em -0.5em black;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    top: 70px;
    background-color: #3a345c;
    z-index: 99;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
  }
  .nav-links li {
    opacity: 0;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    padding-top: 50px;
  }
  .nav-links li a {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .burger {
    display: block;
  }
}

.nav-active {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

@keyframes navLinkFade {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(50px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}


/* Work within Stack Snippets window height */

.nav-links li {
  padding: 10px;
}


/* Answer */

.answer .fix {
  position: relative;
}

.answer .nav-links {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="fix">
      <header>
        <div class="container">
          <nav>
            <a style="height: 70px;"></a>
            <ul class="nav-links">
              <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="/" onclick="scroll_to_chapters();return false;">Chapters</a></li>
              <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="/links">Links</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="burger">
              <div class="line1"></div>
              <div class="line2"></div>
              <div class="line3"></div>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
    <button onclick="toggleAnswer(this);">Click to try with answer</button>
    <div style="height: 500px;">
    </div>
    <div class="chapter_list">
      <h2 style="color: white; padding-left: 10px;">Chapter list</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

- I do not know what is wrong with `scrollIntoView`, but I remark that when I move the chapiters parts to be a direct child of body, that problem disapear.
- However, there is a way to do that same behavior without any js code:

1. In your CSS code, add `scroll-behavior: smooth;` to the root.
2. Add an id to the chapiter : `<div id="chap_id" class="chapter_list">`
3. Turn the href attribut of chapiter link in to : an page#id link : `<a href="page_chapters#chap_id">`

You can find a doc on `scroll-behavior` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior).

Comment: I tried to scroll using HTML ids before, but the thing is, on mobile view, when you click Chapters, you scroll into the chapter section, but you also need to close the navbar and enable scrolling again.

Answer (score -1):

So you are using the body as overscroll and there is also a wrapper with the same height (and it's basically the same as the body) with an overscroll hidden.

Your menu you let slide in has a 100% height, so the bottom is at nav:height + 100%. I assume the scroll into view first scrolls the wrapper (as it overflows the nav:height) and then it scrolls the body. Making the nav-bar disappear, as the overflow is hidden.

You can fix this by adjusting the menu height to make it actually 100% in height: e.g. CSS: calc(100% - 70px) or using flex-box and let the menu flex:1.

Answer (score -1):

You have to fix you navbar using "position: fixed" property. Add & Modify given CSS

Here is the result

[image]

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    
    /*ADD This*/
    .fix {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    
    /*modify this*/
    .nav-links {
        height: 100vh;
    }
    .content {
        margin-top: 90px;
    }
}
```

Comment: The navbar disappears when using the scrollIntoView function he doesn't want it to be fixed to top.

Comment: I tried this. It doesn't disappear now but the navbar is now fixed to the top.

Comment: Look at my answer